# Trouble with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, arraylist

I have a trouble in my app retrieving my data from parse.com
I just wanted to recover data from website in an ArrayList made  with a custom class, for using later in my app
Here is code but I can't test it on my emulator because my app crashes on boot, despite I don't have coding errors
PS: I'm very new in android coding, so any help is well accepted!

```
    final int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryP = ParseQuery.getQuery("Menu");
    queryP.orderByAscending("Id");

    queryP.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> MenuList, ParseException e) {
            int Id_c;
            String Image_c;
            String Name_c;
            String Description_c;
            String Type_c;
            Double Cost_c;
            ArrayList<Plate> FullMenu = new ArrayList<Plate>();
            Plate plate;
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject plate_o : MenuList) {
                    Id_c = plate_o.getInt("Id");
                    Image_c = plate_o.getString("Image");
                    Name_c = plate_o.getString("Name");
                    Description_c = plate_o.getString("Description");
                    Type_c = plate_o.getString("Type");
                    Cost_c = plate_o.getDouble("Cost");
                    String text = Name_c;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                    FullMenu.add(Id_c, new Plate(Id_c, Image_c, Name_c, Description_c, Type_c, Cost_c));
                    plate = FullMenu.get(Id_c);
                    if (plate.getId() % 5 == 0) {
                        text = plate.getName();
                        toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }

                }
            }
            else {
                String text = "The get request failed.";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is my logcat

```
01-02 19:18:58.916 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-02 19:18:58.916 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp I/art: Late-enabling JIT
01-02 19:18:58.918 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
01-02 19:18:58.962 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/mycompany.restaurantapp-2/lib/x86
01-02 19:18:59.401 4406-4438/mycompany.restaurantapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-02 19:18:59.446 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa335d700, tid 4406
01-02 19:18:59.542 4406-4438/mycompany.restaurantapp D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa335d8d0, tid 4438
01-02 19:18:59.556 4406-4438/mycompany.restaurantapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-02 19:18:59.703 4406-4438/mycompany.restaurantapp W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-02 19:18:59.704 4406-4438/mycompany.restaurantapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad79f160, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: mycompany.restaurantapp, PID: 4406
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:147)
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at mycompany.restaurantapp.MainActivity$1.done(MainActivity.java:91)
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at mycompany.restaurantapp.MainActivity$1.done(MainActivity.java:69)
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-02 19:19:04.799 4406-4406/mycompany.restaurantapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-02 19:19:11.067 4406-4406/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4406 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have coding errors"? Is it that the code compiles?

Comment: I posted my logcat, thank you for helping me!

Comment: I mean that before using ArrayList, everything was going correctly, i used toast to see if my query was correct and it worked, so I think it's a problem with that variable, but Android Studio doesn't give me any errors during compilation. Thank you too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FullMenu.add(Id_c, new Plate(Id_c, Image_c, Name_c, Description_c, Type_c, Cost_c));
```

The wrong line. You're trying to add the element to empty ArrayList at certain position. Try to make it like this

```
FullMenu.add(new Plate(Id_c, Image_c, Name_c, Description_c, Type_c, Cost_c));
```

If you want to have an access by id as key you should use Map structure.